# De-register jQuery from WordPress functions.php

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, wordpress

Ok, so I already hav found many postings that answer the question "How do I de-register jQuery from WordPress".  But unfortunately my problem is more complex than that.

I am using the WP eCommerce plugin and the plugin is registering jQuery which conflicts with the main sites use and registration of jQuery.

Does anyone know a way from functions.php to de-register the hook from `wp_head()` that is added by WP eCommerce.  I just don't want to do a hackjob on this so I'm looking to make this change modularly (e.g. include it in functions.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, latest WP-ecommerce does not register jQuery itself, but uses a default jQuery from your WordPress installation. That means that to change the version of jQuery, you need to add you action handler to `wp_head` with the priority value of `9` - it will be handled right after default jQuery is registered by WP. So you'll be able to replace jQuery with some other version.